# Text file with columns and records, analyze Python

Tags: python, file

I have text file with some columns and records(<1000 records).

> Name Surname Age Grade Faculty
>
> Chris M 20 5 Electronics
>
> Jack A 22 3 Computer science
>
> Michael J 21 4 Computer science
>
> ...

Now I want type a functions with dicitionary.

- 1) Show students names with 22 age .
- 2) Show students of Electronics.

Example 1) 
'Chris': 20,

My code:

```
a = {}
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       k,v = line.split(' ') #spacebar in file
       a[k.strip()] = v.strip()
```

But of course not working because I have not idea.

What would be the best way to do this in Python?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: You're making good progress on your own.  The first step is to handle splitting the line.  You've got a good idea there, but things like "Computer science" will not split right.  So here's a hint: `split(line, 4)` , for e.g. the second line, will return `['Jack', 'A', '22', '3', 'Computer science']`, i.e. it will split no more than 4 times.

Comment: Wow, I got upvotes for invalid code.  `line.split(' ', 4)` is the proper syntax.  Once you have your line split, figure out what your next major steps would be.  (You will need a dictionary, and probably dictionary comprehensions.)

Comment: Hmmm, I try repair my code! Maybe someone has a better idea.

Comment: Still not working. I don't know how to link everything to the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you a hint on building a dictionary:

```
a = []
with open("file.txt") as f:
    keys = f.readline().strip().split(' ', 4)
    for line in f:
       val = line.strip().split(' ', 4) # spacebar in file
       a.append(dict(zip(keys, val)))
```

Now `a` contains a list of dictionaries like this one:

```
{'Name': 'Chris', 
 'Surname': 'M', 
 'Age': '20', 
 'Grade': '5', 
 'Faculty': 'Electronics'
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. What if the 4nd column will be a date? 
For example Chris M 22 3 22 04 2010 Electronics , how can i repair the code?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is Pandas. Read data from file into DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep=' ')
```

1) Show students names with 22 age.

```
result = df[df['Age'] == 22]
```

2) Show students of Electronics.

```
result = df[df['Faculty'] == 'Electronics']
```

Comment: What happens in this case with Computer Science?  There's a space there, that would add an extra column.

Comment: And i can't use additional modules :( I read about it. My idea: all records(line by line) direct to list and then operate on lists with my data.